# Multiple inputs in one textbox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Is it possible to store a data in a `TextBox` or `Label` from three others textboxes?
For example- textBox1 contains 01, textBox2 contains 02, textBox3 contains 03.
The final textBox output will be 010203 and this data will be stored in the database. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have 3 separate entries in your source system, why are you combining them in the database? Also yes what you are asking is easy to do, please show us what attempts you have made and in what way the do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Text` property specifically for this purpose.
You can just concatenate the `Text` of all the three `TextBox`(s).

Are you looking for this:-

```
    finalTextBox.Text = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text ;
                //and
    finalLabel.Text = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text ;
    // logic for storing in a database.   
    // finalTextBox is the final TextBox in which you want to store the contents of other textboxes.
    // textBox1,2 and 3 are the three textboxes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just concatenate the text property textbox1,textbox2 and textbox3 into the text property of the other textbox3. You'll have to implement the DB update logic separately.